# vb6-Getting the physical address of network adapter on Windows 7 and later

Tags: networking, vb6, hardware

I have to apply a protection mechanism to a vb6 software, and we have decided to go ahead with using the hardware address of network card (MAC Address) for generating the keys. I have this piece of code with me which does the same. I believe that it is working on in Windows XP.

```
Option Explicit

'
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Used to get the MAC address.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Private Const NCBNAMSZ As Long = 16
Private Const NCBENUM As Long = &H37
Private Const NCBRESET As Long = &H32
Private Const NCBASTAT As Long = &H33
Private Const HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY As Long = &H8
Private Const HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS As Long = &H4

Private Type NET_CONTROL_BLOCK  'NCB
    ncb_command    As Byte
    ncb_retcode    As Byte
    ncb_lsn        As Byte
    ncb_num        As Byte
    ncb_buffer     As Long
    ncb_length     As Integer
    ncb_callname   As String * NCBNAMSZ
    ncb_name       As String * NCBNAMSZ
    ncb_rto        As Byte
    ncb_sto        As Byte
    ncb_post       As Long
    ncb_lana_num   As Byte
    ncb_cmd_cplt   As Byte
    ncb_reserve(9) As Byte 'Reserved, must be 0
    ncb_event      As Long
End Type

Private Type ADAPTER_STATUS
    adapter_address(5) As Byte
    rev_major          As Byte
    reserved0          As Byte
    adapter_type       As Byte
    rev_minor          As Byte
    duration           As Integer
    frmr_recv          As Integer
    frmr_xmit          As Integer
    iframe_recv_err    As Integer
    xmit_aborts        As Integer
    xmit_success       As Long
    recv_success       As Long
    iframe_xmit_err    As Integer
    recv_buff_unavail  As Integer
    t1_timeouts        As Integer
    ti_timeouts        As Integer
    Reserved1          As Long
    free_ncbs          As Integer
    max_cfg_ncbs       As Integer
    max_ncbs           As Integer
    xmit_buf_unavail   As Integer
    max_dgram_size     As Integer
    pending_sess       As Integer
    max_cfg_sess       As Integer
    max_sess           As Integer
    max_sess_pkt_size  As Integer
    name_count         As Integer
End Type

Private Type NAME_BUFFER
    name_(0 To NCBNAMSZ - 1) As Byte
    name_num                 As Byte
    name_flags               As Byte
End Type

Private Type ASTAT
    adapt             As ADAPTER_STATUS
    NameBuff(0 To 29) As NAME_BUFFER
End Type

Private Declare Function Netbios Lib "netapi32" _
        (pncb As NET_CONTROL_BLOCK) As Byte

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
        Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, ByVal _
        hpvSource As Long, ByVal cbCopy As Long)

Private Declare Function GetProcessHeap Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function HeapAlloc Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hHeap As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function HeapFree Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hHeap As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        lpMem As Any) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim strMACAddress As String

    strMACAddress = fGetMacAddress()

    If strMACAddress <> "" Then
        Call MsgBox(strMACAddress, vbInformation, "MAC Address")
    End If

End Sub

Private Function fGetMacAddress() As String
    Dim l As Long
    Dim lngError As Long
    Dim lngSize As Long
    Dim pAdapt As Long
    Dim pAddrStr As Long
    Dim pASTAT As Long
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim strMACAddress As String
    Dim AST As ASTAT
    Dim NCB As NET_CONTROL_BLOCK

    '
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Get the network interface card's MAC address.
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    fGetMacAddress = ""
    strMACAddress = ""

    NCB.ncb_command = NCBRESET
    Call Netbios(NCB)

    NCB.ncb_callname = "*               "
    NCB.ncb_command = NCBASTAT
    NCB.ncb_lana_num = 0
    NCB.ncb_length = Len(AST)

    pASTAT = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS Or _
                       HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, NCB.ncb_length)
    If pASTAT = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    NCB.ncb_buffer = pASTAT
    Call Netbios(NCB)

    Call CopyMemory(AST, NCB.ncb_buffer, Len(AST))

    strMACAddress = Right$("00" & Hex(AST.adapt.adapter_address(0)), 2) & _
                    Right$("00" & Hex(AST.adapt.adapter_address(1)), 2) & _
                    Right$("00" & Hex(AST.adapt.adapter_address(2)), 2) & _
                    Right$("00" & Hex(AST.adapt.adapter_address(3)), 2) & _
                    Right$("00" & Hex(AST.adapt.adapter_address(4)), 2) & _
                    Right$("00" & Hex(AST.adapt.adapter_address(5)), 2)

    Call HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pASTAT)

    fGetMacAddress = strMACAddress
    GoTo NormalExit

ErrorHandler:
    Call MsgBox(Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error")

NormalExit:
    End Function
```

Reference: [118623](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118623)

When I run this code on Windows 7. It only returns the MAC Address as `00000000`. I have tried on 5 PCs and the result is the same. Please help :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Dim myWMI As Object, myObj As Object, Itm

Set myWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set myObj = myWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM " & _
                 "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration " & _
                 "WHERE IPEnabled = True")
For Each Itm In myObj
    MsgBox (Itm.IPAddress(0))
    MsgBox (Itm.MACAddress)
    Exit For
Next
```

find with google : http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=216672

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function MACid() As String
Dim computer As String
Dim wmi As Variant
Dim query As Variant
Dim mac As Variant
Dim mac_ids As String

    computer = "."
    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
        "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
        computer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set query = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled = true")

    For Each mac In query
        mac_ids = mac_ids & ", " & mac.MacAddress
    Next mac
    If Len(mac_ids) > 0 Then mac_ids = Mid$(mac_ids, 3)

    MACid = mac_ids
End Function
```